# How to get the content height of each page in android with or without javaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, webclient

I want to get the content height of each webpage one by one. But I am not getting that. If I am loading page separately then I am able to get the height of each page. But if I tried to get content height of webpage continuously then I failed.

Here is my code-

```
StringBuffer content;
     String temp;

         for(i=tempstart_index;i<=tempend_index;i++)
                {
                Log.i("value of i",i+1+"");

                content+=decrypted(i);
                temp1=decrypted(i);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                    {
                        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getContentHeight(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight);");
                        int initialpageheight=webview.getContentHeight();

                        if(initialpageheight>0)
                        {
                            webheight=initialpageheight;

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+initialpageheight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.i("page finish","" +webheight);

                            initialpage=webheight;
                            if(pagenumber>0)
                            {
                            webview.scrollTo(0, webheight);
                            }
                                         }
         }});
         webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/KH_Brown_Fixed_Layout/",temp1,
     "text/html", "utf-8",null);
                }
         return content;
         }
```

then I am displaying the all merged page as a one page after merging string-

//here reflowable() reading html and merging them and after merging returning it.

```
 String ds=reflowable();
                webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/KH_Brown_Fixed_Layout/", ds, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: please now help me and forgive 4 any mistake ,please do not decrement points please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript you can get the height of the page on a webkit browser with:

`window.innerHeight`

As to what else you're attempting in there, I have no clue, but that'll give you the height in your Android browser.

Comment: If it's good advice and works, don't forget to up vote and accept.

Comment: tkone but if i am using webview.scrollHeight() then it is giving some value but in case of innerHeight it is not giving any value

Comment: Well, your code up there?  That's not JavaScript.  That's Java. I wouldn't expect `webview.innerHeight` to work since `webview` is an instantiation of a Java class.  I have no clue what methods and properties the `webview` class makes available.  But your question is how do you obtain the height of the viewport in JavaScript.  That is how you do it on an Android device.  Now if you're unsure of how to do execute that code from Java on an Android device, that's a different question.

Comment: You should read up on [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) from the Android reference, specially `addJavascriptinterface`.  This will allow you to control your app via javascript.  You could use this to pass the information back into your app.

Comment: yes tkone but here in andoid we can add java script interface like- webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");                                                                                  and after loading string data to webview we can get height of webview content   - webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getContentHeight(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight);");

Comment: Well then it sounds like you'd know how to call window.innerHeight: `webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.innerHeight");` or some variant thereof.

Comment: hello tkone i tried but this is not working but know after wrapping webview size(viewport) i can get the scrollheight() and it is giving the accurate value approximately ,thanks a lot for you advice